# Andengine - How to move a part of an object, like a hand or leg

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

```
Sprite Button = new Sprite(){
   @Override
   public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pEvent, float pX, float pY){
       if(pEvent.isActionDown){
           //Do something when clicked
           return true;
       } else return false;
   }
};
Scene.attachChild(Button);
Scene.registerTouchArea(Button);
```

I am assuming that touchlistener is calling this but I want to know how to add a punch or kick like Street Fighter games when the screen is touched.

I mean, how can I move a part of my object, like a hand, leg, etc. when the screen is touched?
If the answer is too long can you show me a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you can use TiledTextureRegion to get tiles with specified states of your object like ex: standing, crouching etc. You can change texture tile using:

```
yourSprite.setCurrentTileIndex(index);
```